# Bad code style deemed failure by Jenkins/checkstyle

Tags: java, playframework, jenkins, checkstyle

I'm using Jenkins to test a Java software project (using the play web framework but that shouldn't really matter).

Part of the test is about code style, for which I use checkstyle. I tried to set up my job in the following manner:

- I execute checkstyle via command line, which generates a report in xml

`checkstyle -c /usr/share/checkstyle/sun_checks.xml -f xml -r app test -o checkstyle.xml`

- Then I add a post-build action using [this Jenkins plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Checkstyle+Plugin), which reads the xml report and integrates into the build results

So, now my problem is the following: when there are any style problems in the code, Jenkins deems the job as a failure. By default, the post-build action is not carried out in this case.

One can change this, so that a report is generated nonetheless, though it still bugs me that bad code style is considered a failure. That might be subjective, I reckon. Anyway, is there a way to change this? And quite generally, how does Jenkins determine whether a command shell is a failure?

Comment: How are you building the project? Are you using a build tool of any kind (ant/maven)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you look at the source code for the `Main` class of checkstyle ([link](http://sourceforge.net/p/checkstyle/code/ci/tip/tree/src/checkstyle/com/puppycrawl/tools/checkstyle/Main.java)), you'll see that the exit code is the number of style problems found (or 1 in some exceptional cases).

This is what Jenkins is paying attention to: an exit code of 0 canonically indicates success, and a non-zero code indicates failure.

I think your solution is to make the exit code be 0 unconditionally.  A (bash) command for this would be

```
checkstyle <arguments...> || true
```

More generally, you could write a little wrapper script that would run checkstyle and then exit with a code of 0.

Comment: I haven't looked at the problem for a while but that solves it. Thanks you for the answer!